# How/in what format are mysql results transferred over the internet?

Tags: javascript, mysql, database-connection, sequelize.js

Im making an sql query which returns a large data set. 
When exported into CSV, the resulting file is 50Mb in size.

After the sql results have been processed by the SQL ORM( Sequelize ) - the resulting data set(containing all the data received from DB) is 800kb.

The questing is: if sequelize makes the query and is loading the results from the db, is it loading the data in similar format as CSV( with all the duplicate rows/data created due to joins - 50MB) or will the result set be sent over as a special data structure which will remove all the duplicate rows/info and reconstruct them on the other side ?

Im trying to figure out where the slow api response time is coming from. 
I have a hunch that it could be due to large data set but im not sure. 
If the api can send the same data to the client in json format(800kb) then its possible that SQL is doing the same and is only transferring 800kb as well.

Comment: I would think it uses its own binary format when going from server to client. I highly doubt it would be CSV. It might say so somewhere in the docs/spec. You might be able to watch the traffic using something like wireshark

Comment: possibly json. It is light weighted

Comment: I'd imagine JSON would be heavier than CSV with how much extra text is involved.

Comment: Maybe read this, in fact: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/PAGE_PROTOCOL.html

Comment: Speaking from experience, huge data sets like that are expensive to transfer and process. Is there no way you could break it up or paginate? Also, is the query running long, or is it just the data transfer (you can test this by replacing the columns you're selecting with `COUNT(*)`)? The other way to diagnose the query is by putting `EXPLAIN` ahead of the `SELECT` statement, and multiplying all of the row counts together to determine how many rows are being touched for each entry (since it could also be an indexing issue).